# Concurrent open statements and Out of Package Error Occurred in when migrated to jboss eap 6.4 from websphere 7.0

Tags: spring, db2, jboss6.x

We are facing below issue when migrated existing application from webspere 7 to jboss eap 6.4. Please help me on solving the issue.

Existing setup:

WAS 7
IBM DB2 database
spring 1.2

Migrated setup:

jboss eap 6.4
IBM DB2 database(no change)
spring 3.2.0

We are facing the issue when we do the load testing on the application.

Issue:

```
Concurrently open statements:
some queries displayed here

Number of statements:  1818
query here
Number of statements:  1756
query here
Number of statements:  368
query here
Number of statements:  255
query here
Number of statements:  13
query here
Number of statements:  6
query here
Number of statements:  3
query here
Number of statements:  1
query here

WARN  [org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher] (ajp-/IP address) exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException:NULLID.XXXX
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:682)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.copyAsUnchainedSQLException(Agent.java:559)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.chainDeferredExceptionsToAgentOrAsConnectionWarnings(Agent.java:514)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Sqlca.getJDBCMessage(Sqlca.java:336)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlExceptionContainer.getMessage(SqlExceptionContainer.java:80)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException.getMessage(SqlException.java:54)
    at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:754) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:764) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:655) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:721) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
    at com.dynatrace.diagnostics.agent.introspection.Introspection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.dynatrace.diagnostics.agent.introspection.Introspection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.dynatrace.diagnostics.agent.introspection.Introspection.MethodException(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:120) [hibernate3.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1272) [hibernate3.jar:]


2018-09-04 04:40:59,251 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-/IP address) SQL Error: -805, SQLState: 51002
2018-09-04 04:40:59,286 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-/10.204.106.115:8109-11) ***** Out of Package Error Occurred (2018-09-04 04:40:59.286) *****
2018-09-04 04:40:59,286 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-/10.204.106.115:8109-11)
2018-09-04 04:40:59,286 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-/10.204.106.115:8109-11) Exception stack trace:
2018-09-04 04:40:59,286 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-/10.204.106.115:8109-11) com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: NULLID.XXXX
```

Comment: are you hitting this issue?  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670200

Comment: You did not say which platform and version of DB2 you're running. Is it DB2 for LUW or z/Os? Which version? Anyways, you must check out `db2diag` log files and get the exact name of the package that is missing. The error code -805 refers to `SQL0805N` and can have a lot of causes.

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause of this issue? I am facing similar issue in my application after the upgrade.